# Mapbox map taking up whole screen

Tags: android, android-layout, mapbox

I have a mapbox map in my android app, but it always takes up the whole screen. I wanted to make it as big as the content below it.

Here's my code (Setting a fixed size doesn't work either):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.travip.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you share your layout file? you should be able to set a fixed size on a Mapbox Mapview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`

in Linear Layout

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help!
I accidentally called

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
```

Instead of

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nearby, container, false);
```

My fragment inflated the wrong layout. I didn't notice, because they looked almost the same